# Outlook API, Custom Account Type

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am looking at doing some serious MS Outlook extensibility, going beyond the concept of e-mail, but still in the realm of messaging.
As such, I will need to be able to make Outlook aware of a new 'Account Type' (i.e., it currently only understands POP, Exchange, etc).
Can anyone point me to an area of the API that may facilitate this functionality, if it exists...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adam,
reading your question about having a new provider you would have to look at creating a new Mapi provider. This is a pretty complicated area a place to start would be MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc979221.aspx also look for the pdf book "Inside mapi" on the internet

There may be other ways to look at the problem though using Addins for outlook that would extend the UI using panes and form regions etc. or and older technique is to use subclassing and hooking.

Marcus